Do all GitHub Desktop users need to have GitLFS installed?
I'm running a project on a team of 32 people. We are all using GitHub desktop. When I setup the repository, I set up GitLFS. Do all 32 people using GitHub Desktop need to install and run the initialization command?
I've done a lot of research and everyone is giving different answers. It sounds like GitHub desktop handles it, but honestly I'm not sure?

We are using Fork for github management. We don't use anything like that.

GitHub Desktop includes a full copy of Git and a number of frequently used extensions, including git-lfs, git-submodule and git-subtree.

You can find them here: GitHubDesktop\app-3.4.5\resources\app\git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
But GitHub Desktop doesn't register its executables in the system path, so users who want to use the commandline or visual studio code etc will not detect git, nor git-lfs. Users will have to add the correct path to their environment, or install git and git-lfs and optionally the Git Credential Manager separately as well.
When users clone a repo that contains LFS content, GitHub Desktop will detect this, download the LFS objects and will prompt the user to initialize LFS on their local repo:

Each user should Initialize GitLFS to install te hooks into their local git repo or run the git lfs init command from their command prompt.
